# App will crash after provision profile of enterprise account expires

Tags: ios, ios-enterprise

App will crash after provision profile of enterprise account expires.
I have thought four ways to update it, but I believe there is a better way.

1.Rebuild app before expire date, and notice users to update by email or phone call.
--This is userful, but users will be seriously affected.
2.Send configuration files with MDM.
--This is awesome, but users may not accept MDM because of privacy.
3.Rebuild app two months before expire date, when users login in the app, show a alert to notice them to update.
--This is userful, and users will be little affected.
4.Rebuild app two months before expire date, when users open the app, read expire date of provision profile, and then show a alert to notice them to update.
--This is userful, and users will be little affected.

Method 3 and method 4 are meaningful, but I want to get a better way that can update the provision profile with no disturb.

Comment: If you haven't distributed the app via an MDM then you can only update the provisioning profile by getting the user to install a new build.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you, it seems that there is no better way.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of an iOS application, while building and archiving, the provisioning details are being embedded into it. Once the app has built, the provisioning information is permanent. There seems to be no solution to your problem without distributing the new build and the existing users.

Comment: If the app is distributed via an MDM then you can push a new provisioning profile as per (2) in the question.

Comment: Thank you all very much, I have gotten your opinion.